# How can I check if a field is not null?

Tags: c#

I am very new in **C#** (I came from Java) and I have the following question.

In an application, on which I am working, I found something like it in the code:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(u.nome))
```

This code simply check if the `nome` field of the `u` object is not an empty\null string.

OK, this is very clear for me, but what can I do to check it if a field is not a string, but is a normal int?

Comment: It is just like in Java. if(yourObject != null)

Comment: What Heslacher said, except that `int` can't be null, as simple as that :) In any case, `string.IsNullOrEmpty` is a shortcut, and an intent-showing way of checking for "emptyness" of a string. It's effectively equivalent to writing `u.nome == null || u.nome == string.Empty`.

Comment: @Luaan, that`s why i have written yourObject ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`int?` is a nullable integer. Just compare it with null

```
if (u.NullableInt != null)
```

or use [`Nullable<T>.HasValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sksw8094%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property (it's matter of taste, but I found this option more readable)

```
if (u.NullableInt.HasValue)
```

NOTE: If you are asking about `int` then its a [value type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx) and it cannot have `null` value. Default value for integer is `0` (but you cannot say if it was assigned to variable or not, thats why nullable type was introduced).

Comment: You could also use **not null** [instead of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70011022/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-not-in-c) **!=**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a few different types, but the most common are:

```
if(someVar != null)
```

And if you're coming from a DB, this is particularly helpful

```
if(someVar != DBNull.Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

`int` is a non-nullable value type, so it can't be null anyway. But for nullable value types (e.g., `int?`, `bool?`) and reference types (any class), you can simply compare with null

```
if(myObj != null) {....}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a *value type* like int, it will have an init value even you don't init it. For int, it's 0.

For a *[reference type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_type_and_reference_type)*, I think you can check like:

```
if(someVar != null)
```

You can see *[Value and Reference Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/4d43ts61(v=vs.90))*.

Answer (score 0):

You can check using this mechanism:

```
static bool CheckIfNullOrDefault<T>(T value)
{
    return object.Equals(value, default(T));
}

double d = 0;
CheckIfNullOrDefault(d); // true
MyClass c = null;
CheckIfNullOrDefault(c); // true
```

Here in the above code, you find T is a reference type. Here it is compared with null. If it has some value, say Boolean, it is false. For double Default(T) is 0d, and it gets validated.