# Validating HTML Calendar Tool in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, html, linq, validation

I'm developing a .NET MVC application. 
In my .cshtml file I have provided a simple calendar tool in one of my textbox as follows :

```
 <input class="form-control" id="createdOn" type="text" />
```

Here's the JS script for it:

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
        $("#createdOn").datepicker();
}
```

Now I want to check whether the user has selected any date in the above metioned text box or not in one of my C# file.

I have a LINQ query which retrieves data and is stored in a variable named "query".

So the code in this C# file goes like this :

```
var query  = ( from //and so on
     select {
         // data to fetch
}
//below is where I'm stuck
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sc.CreatedOn))      // here sc is an entity 
{
      query.Where(w => w.CreatedOn == sc.CreatedOn);
}

return query.ToList();
}
```

So here the above IF Block doesn't seems to validate the CreatedOn properly.
What am I doing wrong?
Can anyone tell a better way to validate it?

Comment: In above code 'sc'  is object of entity Search. In this Search class CreatedOn is declared and has a datatype of string

Answer (score 1):

First, check rather of not your sc.CreatedOn is a DateTime already in your entity.

if yes, then you may need to apply another method to check existence of the CreatedOn,

Normal datetime field

```
DateTime dat = new DateTime();

if (dat==DateTime.MinValue)
{
    //unassigned
}
```

and in case, DateTime

```
 DateTime? dat = null;

 if (!dat.HasValue)
 {
     //unassigned
 }
```

More information From:
[How to check if a DateTime field is not null or empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905733/how-to-check-if-a-datetime-field-is-not-null-or-empty)