# Is there a difference between "!=" and "is not" in C#?

Tags: c#, if-statement, syntax

Is this:

```
if(x != y)
{

}
```

different from this:

```
if (x is not y)
{

}
```

Or are there no differences between the two conditions?

Comment: Does c# have a `not` keyword? I thought the second example would be written `if (!(x is y))`.

Comment: Is or is not would be used to compare type, but == or != would compare the variables’ values

Comment: @JohnWu: Yes, as of C# 9. Along with `or` and `and` keywords. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#logical-patterns

Comment: @JohnWu C# sat too close to VB at a christmas do nearly 2 years ago; ended up catching something called C#ViB-19 - it's never been the same since

Comment: @CaiusJard I know it seems silly at first-glance, but now I love it: being able to do `x is 1 or 2 or 3` is a LOT nicer than doing `( x == 1 || x == 2 || x == 3 )` *and* as a bonus: when `x` is an expression instead of a value then the `is` operator only evaluates `x` _once_, whereas `( x == 1 || x == 2 || x == 3 )` will causes 3 evaluations of `x`.

Comment: @Dai oh the evaluation part sounds really nice!

Comment: @Dai - I really don't know much (if anything) about compilers, but in a case as simple as `( x == 1 || x == 2 || x ==3 )` wouldn't the compiler be able to optimize that down to a single evaluation and then a comparison in the same way as `x is 1 or 2 or 3`? I'm honestly not doubting you for a second - I'm just asking for my own education.

Comment: @Spratty For simple fields or local variables there is generally no difference, but for other types of expressions (for example, computed properties) it can't always safely optimize the first case down to a single evaluation because evaluating `x` might have side effects and the compiler has no way of knowing if the code intended for the expression to be reevaluated after each comparison.

Comment: Waiting for C# and COBOL to converge.... IF X IS EQUAL TO 2 THEN DISPLAY 'YES' END-IF.

Comment: @shoover: Haven't C# and COBOL already converged into NetCOBOL?

Comment: @Toddleson: The question is using `is not`, that isn't just `is` composed with `not`.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

#### Comparison table:

| Operator | `!=` | `is not` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Original purpose | [Value inequality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/equality-operators) | Negated [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#is-operator) |
| Can perform value inequality | **Yes** | **Yes** |
| Can perform negated pattern matching | *No* | **Yes** |
| Can invoke `implicit` operator on left-hand operand | **Yes** | *No* |
| Can invoke `implicit` operator on right-hand operand(s) | **Yes** | **Yes**<sup>1</sup> |
| Is its own operator | **Yes** | *No*<sup>2</sup> |
| Overloadable | [**Yes**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/equality-operators#inequality-operator-) | *No* |
| Since | C# 1.0 | [C# 9.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#logical-patterns)<sup>3</sup> |
| Value-type null-comparison branch [elision](https://ericlippert.com/2013/01/24/five-dollar-words-for-programmers-elision/)<sup>4</sup> | [**Yes**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48685875/does-performing-a-null-check-on-a-generic-cause-boxing) | *No*<sub>[Citation needed]</sub><sup>5</sup> |
| Impossible comparisons | [Error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0019) | [Warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0184) |
| Left operand | Any expression | Any expression |
| Right operand(s) | Any expression | Only constant expressions<sup>6</sup> |
| Syntax | `<any-expr> != <any-expr>` | `<any-expr> is [not] <const-expr> [or|and <const-expr>]*` [and more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/patterns3) |

#### Common examples:

| Example | `!=` | `is not` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Not null | `x != null` | `x is not null` |
| Value inequality example | `x != 'a'` | `x is not 'a'` |
| Runtime type (mis)match | `x.GetType() != typeof(Char)` | `x is not Char`<sup>7</sup> |
| SQL `x NOT IN ( 1, 2, 3 )` | `x != 1 && x != 2 && x != 3` | `x is not 1 or 2 or 3` |

---

To answer the OP's question *directly and specifically*:

```
if( x != y ) { }
// vs:
if( x is not y ) { }
```

- If `x` is an integral value-type (e.g. `int`/ `Int32`) and `y` is a `const-expression` (e.g. `const int y = 123;`) then **no**, there is no difference, and both statements result in the same .NET MSIL bytecode being generated (both with and without compiler optimizations enabled):

  [image]
- If `y` is a type-name (instead of a value name) then there *is* a difference: the first `if` statement is invalid and won't compile, and the `if( x is not y )` statement is a *type pattern* match instead of a *constant pattern* match.

---

Footnotes:

1. ["Constant Pattern"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/patterns#constant-pattern): "When the input value is not an open type, the constant expression is implicitly converted to the type of the matched expression".
2. `x is not null` is more analogous to `!(x == null)` than `x != null`.
3. C# 7.0 introduced some limited forms of *constant-pattern* matching, which was further expanded by C# 8.0, but it wasn't until C# 9.0 that the `not` negation operator (or is it a modifier?) was added.
4. Given a non-constrained generic method, like so:

   ```
   void Foo<T>( T x )
   {
       if( x == null ) { DoSomething(); }

       DoSomethingElse();
   }
   ```

   ...when the JIT instantiates the above generic method (i.e.: [*monomorphization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomorphization)) when `T` is a value-type (`struct`) then the entire `if( x == null ) { DoSomething(); }` statement (*and its block contents*) will be removed by the JIT compiler ("elision"), this is because a value-tupe can never be equal to `null`. While you'd expect that to be handled by any optimizing compiler, I understand that the .NET JIT has specially hardcoded rules for that particular scenario.

   - Curiously in earlier versions of C# (e.g. 7.0) the elision rule only applied to the `==` and `!=` operators, but not the `is` operator, so while `if( x == null ) { DoSomething(); }` would be elided, the statement `if( x is null ) { DoSometing(); }` would *not*, and in fact you would get a compiler error unless `T` was constrained to `where T : class`. Since C# 8.0 this seems to now be allowed for unconstrained generic types.
5. Surprisingly I couldn't find an authoritative source on this (as the published C# specs are now significantly outdated; and I don't want to go through the `csc` source-code to find out either).

   - If neither the C# compiler or JIT do apply impossible-branch-elision in generic code with *Constant-pattern* expressions then I *think* it might simply because it's too hard to do at-present.
6. Note that a *constant-expression* does not mean a *literal-expression*: you can use named `const` values, `enum` members, and so on, even non-trivial raw expressions provided all sub-expressions are also *constant-expressions*.

   - I'm curious if there's any cases where `static readonly` fields could be used though.
7. Note that in the case of `typeof(X) != y.GetType()`, this expression will return `true` when `X` is derived from `y`'s type (as they are different types), but `x is not Y` is actually `false` because `x` *is*  `Y` (because `x` is an instance of a subclass of `Y`). When using `Type` it's better to do something like `typeof(X).IsSubclassOf(y.GetType())`, or the even looser `y.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(X))`.

   - Though in this case, as `Char` is a struct and so cannot participate in a type-hierarchy, so doing `!x.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Char))` would just be silly.

Comment: What does the word 'elison' mean in row 8?

Comment: @dennis_vok I guess he's refering to this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision. Edit queued

Comment: It should probably also be mentioned that `is`/`is not` can only be used with constant values on the right hand side.

Comment: @EtsitpabNioliv In this case it's not copy elision, but a compiler optimization to remove comparisons that only have one outcome. E.g. if `x` is non-nullable `x != null` can always be optimized to `true`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @cg909, definitly a niche term, I swapped the wiki link with https://ericlippert.com/2013/01/24/five-dollar-words-for-programmers-elision/

Comment: @Dai Maybe because the answer has since been edited to something much better? I do agree that the question is poor at best... value comparison is not pattern matching.

Comment: what was the software of the screenshot?

Comment: @VSCode_fanboy LinqPad 6

Answer (score 15):

An additional difference to the ones listed in the excellent accepted answer is that (since C# 7.0), `is` between two NaN values is a pattern that matches, because [`x.Equals(y)` is `true` when both `x` and `y` are NaN,](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=net-6.0) and a NaN value does not have an integral type. Therefore, `is not` between two NaN values returns that the pattern is not a match.

However, C# follows IEEE floating-point and C by [specifying that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#relational-and-type-testing-operators) a `!=` comparison between two NaN values is `true` and an `==` comparison between them is `false`.  This was mainly because [the Intel 8087 floating-point co-processor back in 1980 had no other way to test for NaN.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1573715/4474419)

Comment: Two values that are not numbers cannot be equall after all. Computers sure use such a pleasant logic. Why can more things in life not work like that?

Comment: @NeilMeyer “Einstein argued that there must be simplified explanations of nature, because God is not capricious or arbitrary. No such faith comforts the software engineer.” —Fred Brooks

Comment: The Intel 8087 did have other ways to test for NaN, for example the [FXAM instruction](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/fxam). The main reason was that languages like C were lacking a standardized isNaN primitive.

Comment: @nwellnhof Your link seems to be broken, but thanks for the correction. I’ll look into that some more and edit as appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Nan and null are properties that variables can contain that have no values. Equality checks require an actual value to determine equality. After all the question on whether Sally and Peter has the same amount of apples when nobody knows how many Apples either of them has is meaningless.

Sometimes you want to check if a variable has a property without a value. A basic equality check would not be sufficient for this. That is when is / is not operator is useful. It could be said != is a value check where is / is not a property check.

Comment: While `null` is similar in principle to NaN, there is no discrepancy between `is` and `==` on `null` references. `null == null` evaluates to true. A pattern match between two reference types is specified as consistent with `Equals(Object)`, and “a call to the `Equals(Object)` method is equivalent to a call to the `ReferenceEquals` method.” This in turn is specified as, “`true` if `objA` is the same instance as `objB` or if both are `null`.” Therefore, `null == null` and `null is null` give the same result.

Comment: That is, there is no discrepancy unless `!=` has been overloaded in a surprising way.

Comment: By the way, [the spec says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.0/pattern-matching) that `if (expr is Type v)` was created as a concise replacement for explicit `null` checks. So, MS’ house style favors that over either `v != null` or `v is not null`.

Comment: And the downvote did not come from me, by the way.

Comment: The "You cannot compare values to NaN and NULL" philosophy is _wrong_. There, I said it.  It adds no value to a language and worsens the dev-ex. I'll counter that _it is demonstrably possible_ to design a language with clear, straightforward, and logically consistent rules that allow meaningful comparisons to nulls using equality operators (indeed: C# does it just fine! As does Java, and C++, and more), whereas ISO SQL is rigidly strict about `x = NULL` being `UNKNOWN` and it's a significant _gotcha_ to everyone, from beginners to even experts. `IS NULL` in SQL is just a dogshow hoop.

Comment: "Nan and null are properties that variables can contain that have no values." this is true in a general-sense, when discussing programming-language design in an academic context, especially w.r.t. category-theory - however in C# specifically that is incorrect: in C#/.NET `NaN` only applies to IEEE-754 floats (and no other numeric types), and _`null` is a value in itself_ instead of being conceptualized as _the absence of a value_, as in C# `null` _is_ the value-of-a-reference) - this also applies to `Nullable<T>` (don't call it a monad either).

Comment: @Dai: You've obviously thought about this (+1). In support: while one can formulate logically consistent rules for comparisons involving `null`, things fall apart unavoidably around `NaN`. Reasoning that `NaN /*Not a Number*/ != NaN` makes perfect sense until `x != x /*something != itself*/`. My own philosophising stopped at the realisation that `null` (even as value of a reference) represents *affirmation* of a legitimate - empty placeholder - state, whereas NaN represents *contradiction* - an illegitimate state where a placeholder for things of a type contains a thing not of that type.

Comment: @AlanK You're not wrong, but a better solution to dealing with `NaN` is defining `NaN` as  a _type_ instead of a value (this does require language support for _refinement types_, of course - so us C#/.NET users will need to wait another decade or two...). So all operations on IEEE floats will be redefined as returning `value` or `value | NaN` or `NaN` based on operands and refinements of those operands, and `==` simply wouldn't be defined for the `NaN` type, giving you a compile-time error for `NaN == NaN` - which is much better than a _surprise_ runtime `false` expression result.

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR:** `x != 1 && x != 2 && x != 3`  is equivalent to `x is not 1 and not 2 and not 3` or `x is not (1 or 2 or 3)`

`x is not 1 or 2 or 3`  is equivalent to `x != 1 || x == 2 || x == 3`

---

Maybe a bit late to the party, but examples are meant to clarify.

looking at [@Dai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70011062/1576441) 's Common examples table

`x != 1 && x != 2 && x != 3`  and `x is not 1 or 2 or 3` are supposed to be equivalent (if i am getting right)

But they are not.

The problem is the [Operator precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#precedence-and-order-of-checking)

> The pattern combinators are ordered from the highest precedence to the
> lowest as follows:
>
> - not
> - and
> - or

`x != 1 && x != 2 && x != 3`  is equivalent to `x is not 1 and not 2 and not 3`

`x != 1 && x != 2 && x != 3`  is equivalent to `x is not (1 or 2 or 3)`

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var x = 3;
        if(x is not 1 or 2 or 3){            
            Console.WriteLine("x is not 1 and is not 2 and is not 3");
        }       
    }
}

output: "x is not 1 and is not 2 and is not 3"

        if(x != 1 && x != 2 && x != 3){
            Console.WriteLine("x is not 1 and is not 2 and is not 3");
        }
        else{
            Console.WriteLine("x is 1 or 2 or 3");
        }   

output: "x is 1 or 2 or 3"
```